# Mobile responsive Website loaded into an App for review

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I am developing an website for  client, the website is mobile responsive say www.myresponsivewebsite.com. The client want to bundle this website as a iOS application using the UIwebview and load the website when the App opens.

Now according to the Apple review guidelines
https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#minimum-functionality
says

> Your app should include features, content, and UI that elevate it beyond a repackaged website. If your app is not particularly useful, unique, or “app-like,” it doesn’t belong on the App Store.

So my question is :

- Will the app be rejected for sure with only the website repackaged as an App?
- Having a few native screen and loading the web page would be wise solution to make sure that the app does not get rejected.

Note : The client does not want the app to be fully in Native environment.
Reference : 1] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421002/app-rejected-from-apple-app-store-because-uiwebview-need-some-advice
2] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6735476/will-ios-apps-that-are-just-uiwebviews-be-rejected

Comment: If all the app does is offering a site-specific browser, what do you (or the client) need the app at all?

Comment: Optimize your client's website for mobile devices and I think the effort will be much more practically spent. You can add an app icon to an iPhone home screen and use it to launch an app. With that, and based off of what you have described, it sounds like there would be no benefit with using a native app. Aside from whether or not it would get rejected (which it sounds like it would), it doesn't sound like a good option to create an "app".

Answer (score 2):

Oh it will get rejected, no matter how fancy or how good you want to cover it. If the app is mostly just web, you will get rejected. I didn't even have a web browser involved and it got rejected for "not entertaining enough" but it had to do with medical, so idk.

Try adding tabs (UITabBarController) for different sections, eg. about, contact, etc. with pages designed specifically for this "app" without links so the client can't go off track. For example About tab will show about.html without links. (still think it will be rejected)

Or simply just make an API to load these stuff programmatically?

Comment: This is a crazy dance. Just because the king wants is slaves to dance, slaves dance for him. Thank you for your answer. It is not your fault, you are just the messenger of this nonsense. I just get annoyed if I should go a difficult way if there is a simple and straight forward way...